# Getting error while inserting bulk data in test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, class

I have developed the below test class but getting below error.

**Error:**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   UpdateCaseStatusOnReceiptCreation: execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:
>   5009E00000823WHQAY
>
> Class.CaseStatusUpdateHelper.onAfterInsert: line 50, column 1
>   Trigger.UpdateCaseStatusOnReceiptCreation: line 16, column 1: []

**Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger UpdateCaseStatusOnReceiptCreation on Receipt__c(after insert) {
   CaseStatusUpdateHelper objCaseStatusUpdateHelper= new CaseStatusUpdateHelper();
   Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap = Receipt__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

   if (trigger.isInsert){
      for(Receipt__c receipt: trigger.new){
           if(recordTypeMap.get(receipt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.RECEIPT_RECORDTYPE)){

           objCaseStatusUpdateHelper.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
           }
      }    
   }   

}
```

**Helper Class:**

```
public class CaseStatusUpdateHelper{
  Set<Id> receiptIDSet = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> caseIDSet = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Case> casesToUpdate = new Set<Case>();
  List<Case> casesToUpdateList = new List<Case>();

  private static final String caseStatus = 'Closed'; 


  Public void onAfterInsert(List<Receipt__c> receiptID){
      if(receiptID!=null){
          for(Receipt__c rcpt: receiptID){
            receiptIDSet.add(rcpt.id);
          } 

          if(receiptIDSet!=null){
              List<Receipt__c> listOfCases= new List<Receipt__c>([SELECT ID, CaseID__r.Id FROM Receipt__c WHERE ID IN: receiptIDSet]);
                 for(Receipt__c CaseId: listOfCases){
                   caseIDSet.add(CaseId.CaseID__r.Id);
                 }

                 if(caseIDSet != null){
                      List<case> caseList = new List<case>([SELECT Id, status FROM case WHERE ID IN: caseIDSet]);
                         for (Case caseUpdate: caseList){
                             caseUpdate.status = caseStatus;
                             casesToUpdate.add(caseUpdate);
                         }

                         if(casesToUpdate.size() > 0){

                             for(Case casesToUpdateSet : casesToUpdate){
                                 casesToUpdateList.add(casesToUpdateSet);
                             }
                             if(casesToUpdateList.size()>0){
                                      Database.update(casesToUpdateList,false);
                             }
                         }   
                 } 
           }             
      }
   }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class CaseStatusUpdateHelper_Test {

    @isTest 
    private static void onAfterInsrt() {

        // prepare test data
        ID refundRecordtypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Receipt__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(SYSTEM.label.RECEIPT_RECORDTYPE).getRecordTypeID(); 
        System.debug('refundRecordtypeID------------>'+refundRecordtypeID); 

        List<case> caseDataList = new List<case>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
            Case caseData = new Case(Status='Open', Origin='Email');
            caseDataList.add(caseData);
        }
        Insert caseDataList;
        //System.debug('caseDataList---->'+caseDataList);

        List<Id> caseArray=new List<ID>();
        for(Case ABC: caseDataList){

            caseArray.add(ABC.Id);
        }

        System.debug('caseArray@@@@@'+caseArray);


        List<Receipt__c> receiptList = new List<Receipt__c>();


        for(Integer j=0;j<20;j++){


            Receipt__c receipt = new Receipt__c();
            receipt.RecordTypeId = refundRecordtypeID;
            receipt.Status__c = 'Open';
            receipt.CaseID__c = caseArray.get(j);
            System.debug('""""""""""""'+receipt.CaseID__c);
            receiptList.add(receipt);
        }
        Test.startTest();

        insert receiptList;

        Test.stopTest();

        for(Receipt__c A: receiptList){
            List<Receipt__c> B= new List<Receipt__c>([Select ID, Status__c from Receipt__c where Id =: A.Id]);
            System.debug('***********'+B);
        }


        System.debug('receiptList>ID------>'+receiptList);
        //System.debug('receiptList RT------>'+receiptList.RecordTypeId);


        for(Case CaseIdSet: caseDataList){
            CaseIdSet=[SELECT Status FROM CASE WHERE Id =: CaseIdSet.id];
            System.debug('CaseIdSet-------->'+CaseIdSet);
            System.assertEquals('Closed', CaseIdSet.Status);
        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
trigger UpdateCaseStatusOnReceiptCreation on Receipt__c(after insert) {
List<Receipt__c> recpntLst = New List<Receipt__c>();
CaseStatusUpdateHelper objCaseStatusUpdateHelper= new CaseStatusUpdateHelper();
Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap = Receipt__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

   if (trigger.isInsert){
      for(Receipt__c receipt: trigger.new){
           if(recordTypeMap.get(receipt.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.RECEIPT_RECORDTYPE)){

                     recpntLst.add(receipt);
           }
      }
   if(recpntLst.size()>0){
  objCaseStatusUpdateHelper.onAfterInsert(recpntLst);
```

}

```
   }   

}
```

Comment: No need to pass the entire trigger.new list from if block @Surjit

Comment: just dumping code as an answer is not very usefull to other community members facing the same or a similar problem. Preferably, you would want to add an explanation as to why your code works, and what you changed. Please take a moment to review [answer].

Comment: While this change looks like it does fix *an* issue with OP's code, it's not clear to me that it fixes the issue this question is about.